# remove dark background dialogue list

Tags: android

> fragment_available_history

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/drop"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:weightSum="2">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:text="ALL"
                        android:id="@+id/texter"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/mostgrey"
                        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:src="@drawable/downchevron"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/drop"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

> AvailableHistoryFragment.java

```
public class AvailableHistoryFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //SQLiteDB db;
    View drop;
    String options[] = {"ALL","LIKED","CONNECTED","PASSED","EXPIRED"};
    ArrayList<MatchModel> matchList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<MatchModel> selectedOptionMatchList = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectedOption = "ALL";
    AppCompatTextView appCompatTextView;
    ArrayList<String> imageUrl = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> isInterestedStatus = new ArrayList<>() ;
    ArrayList<String> selectedOptionImageUrl =new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> selectedOptionIsInterestedStatus =new ArrayList<>();
    public static View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_available_history, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        drop = view.findViewById(R.id.drop);
        appCompatTextView = (AppCompatTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.texter);

        LoggedInActivity.floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        initializeData();
        initializeForm();

        final DialogueListAdapter dialogueListAdapter = new DialogueListAdapter(getActivity(), options);

        drop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                builderSingle.setAdapter(dialogueListAdapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                String name = dialogueListAdapter.getItem(which);
                                appCompatTextView.setText(name);
                                updateRecyclerView(name);
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                builderSingle.create();
                builderSingle.show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

> adapter_dialogue_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:textColor="@color/dialogue_list"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/data_text"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> DialogueListAdapter

```
public class DialogueListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity activity;
    private final String[] data;

    public DialogueListAdapter(Activity activity, String[] data) {
        super(activity, R.layout.adapter_dialogue_list, data);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.data = data;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_dialogue_list, null, true);
        TextView textTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.data_text);
        textTitle.setText(data[position]);
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

> Theme

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppFullScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
    <style name="mystyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">#1E9CFD</item>
    </style>
    <style name="myster" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="MySwitch" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/most_used</item>
        <!-- inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/mostgrey</item>
        <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">@color/mostgrey</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

> I am getting black background around the dialogue in Android API Level
>   25 Phone. Could you help to remove that. I have tried to set the
>   background color in the xml in the fragment as well as the dialogue
>   list adapter. Find attached screenshot to check the top and bottom
>   black line. My AppTheme is "AppTheme" and fragment theme is "myster"

[image]

Comment: Whats you app theme ? post here

Comment: I have edited the question @ADM

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do the trick.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builderSingle = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            this);
    builderSingle.setAdapter(dialogueListAdapter,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String name = dialogueListAdapter.getItem(which);
                    appCompatTextView.setText(name);
                    updateRecyclerView(name);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builderSingle.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));
    alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: I have not tested it myself give it a try and let me know if it works or not. Thx

Comment: I will test and let you know. BTW I have changed myster "Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" to "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" and it worked. Thanks for help

Comment: Yeah .. that will work. I missed it . XD . Cause I already using this theme so I didn't get the same problem you did . Thx anyway